# In python, how to begin a re.sub from a certain position in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I need to put a newline after every sentence that ends with a period, but only after the word ITEM appears in the string. Suppose the string is what is in quotes:

"I don't. want this. broken up.

ITEM blah blah blah
I do. Want. These. broken up."

The result I want is:

"I don't. want this. broken up.
ITEM blah blah blah

I do.

Want.

These.

broken up."

I'm using:

f = re.sub('. ', '. \r\n', f)

but it's, of course, breaking up the top stuff, too.
Googling hasn't given me the answer. What do I do?

Comment: I guess I can include in the search part: ITEM(.*?). Is that the too-obvious-to-give answer?

Comment: Actually, no that putting in ITEM doesn't work to change all the sentences after it. I do want to start the re.sub after ITEM.

Comment: Okay, I have a workaround: I split the file at ITEM and do the re.sub on the bottom part, then concatenate the unchanged top + ITEM + fixed bottom.